# Non-programmer using Sequel Ace, how to resolve "Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size" error?

Tags: mysql, mac-os-x

I don't know MySQL but I wanted to glance through some data in a table. I imported the database into Sequel Ace (MacOS) and had no trouble browsing through the tables, but when attempting to sort one column in a larger table I received an "Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size" error.

How do I make that happen?

I have MySQL installed and running.

Comment: What is the current value?  How much RAM do you have?

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,366143,376017#msg-376017

how to create a my.cnf file and add

```
[mysqld]
sort_buffer_size = 1M
```

And then increase it when it still makes troubles

Comment: Thank you. Problem solved!